# Problema com INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite,

Estou a fazer um `inner join` de 3 tabelas mas não estou a conseguir por a funcionar deve ter algum erro que não estou a conseguir detectar ou fazer da forma correcta sou novo nisto dos `inner join`

**PHP**

```
SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM categorias_estabelecimentos WHERE categoria_slug = :categoria_slug) FROM estabelecimentos
INNER JOIN estabelecimentos_anexos ON estabelecimentos_anexos.id_mae = estabelecimentos.id
WHERE estabelecimentos.id = categorias_estabelecimentos.estabelecimento_id
AND estabelecimentos.activo = :activo
AND estabelecimentos_anexos.seccao = :seccao
ORDER BY pos ASC
```

Comment: Select *. (ponto e não virgula), veja se resolve.

Comment: Não resolve com o ponto ao testar directamente no phpmyadmin da erro de `SQL syntax` com a virgula da `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o erro está aqui:

```
(SELECT * FROM categorias_estabelecimentos WHERE categoria_slug = :categoria_slug)
```

Só deve retornar um campo

Logo deve ser assim:

```
(SELECT ce.campo FROM categorias_estabelecimentos ce WHERE ce.categoria_slug = :categoria_slug)
```

Mas procure fazer da forma abaixo pois é mais perfomático:

```
SELECT 
e.*, 
ea.*,
ce.*
FROM 
estabelecimentos e
INNER JOIN estabelecimentos_anexos ea ON ea.id_mae = e.id
INNER JOIN categorias_estabelecimentos ce ON ce.categoria_slug = e.categoria_slug
WHERE 
AND e.activo = :activo
AND ea.seccao = :seccao
```

Answer (score 1):

Você esta utilizando um `SELECT` dentro de outro `SELECT` ou sejá um `sub-SELECT`.

Neste caso o seu retorno do `sub-SELECT` deve retornar um única coluna, ou então você deve utilizar um função para que os dados se tornem um único registro. Lembrando ainda que você deve nomear este retorno através do `AS`.

#### Exemplo

```
SELECT
    A.a,
    (
        SELECT
            B.b   // UNICO DADO
        FROM
            table_b B
        WHERE
            B.a = A.a
    ) AS 'A.b'
FROM
    table_a A
```